# Problem on a dense open subset and a closed point of an affine scheme

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring, let $U \subseteq \operatorname{Spec} R = X$ be a dense open subset and let $\mathfrak{m}$ be a maximal ideal in $X-U$.

Is there a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p} \subseteq \mathfrak{m}$ with $\mathfrak{p} \in U$ and $\dim R/\mathfrak{p} = 1$?

It is obviously false when $\operatorname{ht} \mathfrak{m} = 0$, so let me assume that $R$ is catenary and $\operatorname{ht} \mathfrak{m} > 0$.

This problem rises from Mumford's book "Lectures on Curves on an Algebraic Surfaces" p.109, with some typo fixed. In that situation, $X$ is a closed subscheme of a Grassmannian, which (I think) is catenary.

Comment: After various reductions (localization at a maximal ideal, taking the reduced ring, reducing the size of $U$ using the prime avoidance lemma, quotienting by a minimal prime ideal), I arrive at the following question (assuming $R$ is Noetherian) – which looks like it should be well-known: let $R$ be a local catenary Noetherian domain of dimension $d>0$. Let $f \in R$ be nonzero, noninvertible. Can the dimension of $R_f$ be at most $d-2$?

Comment: @Mindlack [This MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/68386/can-we-say-anything-about-the-krull-dimension-of-a-localization) might help - specifically, Hailong Dao's answer.

Comment: Another possibility is to use induction on the dimension of $R$: find a prime ideal of height $1$ not containing $f$, and quotient by it. If it’s impossible, then $R[1/f]$ is a field and in particular $R$ has finitely many prime ideals of height $1$ (all containing $f$). But if $R$ is an essentially finitely generated $k$-algebra, Noether normalization should provide some sort of obstruction (something like this: let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a maximal ideal of $k[t_1,\ldots,t_d]$ with $d \geq 2$, then it contains infinitely many irreducible elements) in dimension $\geq 2$.